# Android: get All Notifications TransactionTooLargeException Exception

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am using `NotificationListenerService` to listen the notifications of the device, but when I tried to get all notifications on the panel using the method:

```
StatusBarNotification[] array = this.getActiveNotifications();
```

I got the `TransactionTooLargeException`, I think it's because two many notifications on my notification panel. Then how can I do on this?